# How to use Python with beautifulsoup to merge siblings

Tags: python, html

How do I merge siblings together and display the output one beside each other.

**EX.**

```
dat="""
<div class="col-md-1">
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
<th>Name:</th>
<td><strong>John</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Last Name:</th>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Email:</th>
<td>jd@mail.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(dat, 'html.parser')
for buf in soup.find_all(class_="table"):
   ope = buf.get_text("\n", strip=True)
   print ope
```

**When run it produces:**

```
Name:
John
Last Name:
Doe
Email:
jd@mail.com
```

**What I need:**

```
Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Email: jd@mail.com
```

Can it be done in a list and every new "tr" tag put a new line?

**EDIT:**
 [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) answer worked but strangely after the output I would get "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" To fix that just put a try:except block.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(dat, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select(".table tr"):
 try:   
         (label, value) = row.find_all(["th", "td"])
     print(label.get_text() + " " + value.get_text())
 except ValueError:
     continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't process the table *row by row*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(dat, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select(".table tr"):
    label, value = row.find_all(["th", "td"])
    print(label.get_text() + " " + value.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Email: jd@mail.com
```

Comment: Thanks, had to modify it up a bit, as after outout it showed ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(dat, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': ['table', 'table-hover']})
for buf in table:
    for row in buf.find_all('tr'):
        print(row.th.string, row.td.string)
```

Output

```
Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Email: jd@mail.com
```

Comment: Thanks yours worked too but I couldn't figure out how to remove the "(u'...', u'...') tags.